# How to pass GET parameters to rewritten URL?

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an `.htaccess` rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?q=$1
```

What this does is, if someone visits `http://example.com/search/test` the URI that is really processed is `http://www.example.com/search.php?q=test`.

Now, if I try to pass an extra random GET parameter to my rewritten URL, the parameter is ignored. So if I try to do visit here:

`http://www.example.com/search/whatever?extra=true`

The parameter `extra` is ignored. It doesn't seem to get passed at all.

Can this problem be fixed? If so, how?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are looking for the `Q`uery `S`tring `A`ppend flag - e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

See the [`mod_rewrite` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for a full description of RewriteRule flags.

Comment: Ah nice! I knew there was something like that. I'm a `.htaccess` noob.

Comment: Is there a way to add QSA to all rules

Comment: Hi @danlefree Know it's an old question, but using Wamp, when i do this, all my stylesheets, scripts etc lose reference. how can I solve that?